# Does the value of a convergent series equal the sum of its non-negative terms minus the sum of the absolute values of its negative terms?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In the lecture note [*Sums Over Sets*](http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math461/SumsOverSets.pdf) it says that it is possible to define absolutely
convergent sums with negative terms, using the definition
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in S} f(s) = \sum_{\substack{s \in S \\ f(s) \geq 0}} f(s) - \sum_{\substack{s \in S \\ f(s) < 0}} |f(s)|
\end{equation}
I am now wondering whether this is compatible with series. It is learnt in calculus class that if we permute (infinitely many) terms of an absolutely convergent series, we can still obtain an absolutely convergent one which converges to the same number. Moreover, it is learnt that the associative law holds for the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, so we can say
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = (a_1+\dots+a_{n_1}) + (a_{n_1+1}+\dots+a_{n_2})+\dots
\end{equation}
Well, I have to confess that this is true if there is finite terms in each parenthesis, even if there might be infinitely many parentheses, but I don't know whether it is true if there is infinitely many terms in each parenthesis, and, provided it's true, can we then deduce that an absolutely convergent series with infinitely many negative and non-negative terms can be calculated by subtracting the sum of the absolute values of all negative terms from the sum of all non-negative terms, just as the definition in that lecture note?

Answer (score 1):

As $f(s)<0$
$$\Rightarrow \left | f(s) \right | =-f(s)$$
Thus we get the desired result

Comment: I hope you get it